# How to get rid of "no attribute enums error" in google cloud vision API

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am currently using the google cloud vision API in order to translate a pdf document and I have come up with an error in my code. I am currently using the statements

```
feature = vision_v1.types.Feature(
    type=vision_v1.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
```

but I am getting the error saying:

```
"AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.vision_v1' has no attribute 'enums'"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error you just need to change `enums` to `type` on your line of code see [Feature reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/vision_v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Feature). Also change `type` to `type_` since this is the accepted parameter name.

> class google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Feature(mapping=None, *,
> ignore_unknown_fields=False, **kwargs) Bases: proto.message.Message
>
> The type of Google Cloud Vision API detection to perform, and the
> maximum number of results to return for that type. Multiple Feature
> objects can be specified in the features list.
>
> - type_
>
>   - The feature type.
> - Type: google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Feature.Type

See code below on for the fix:

```
feature = vision_v1.types.Feature( type_=vision_v1.types.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
```